# Substitute chars on Java 1.4 InputStream

Tags: java, parsing, inputstream

I have an InputStream that is returning, for example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?><env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><bbs:rule xmlns:bbs="http://com.foo/bbs">
```

I then pass the stream to a method that return a byte array.
I'd like to substitute "com.foo" with something else, like "org.bar" before I pass to the byte[] method.

What is a good way to do that?

Comment: Which InputStream impl are you using?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a bytearray you can transform it into a String. Pay attention to the encoding, in the example I use utf-8. I think this is a simple way to do that:

```
String newString = new String(byteArray, "utf-8");
newString = newString.replace("com.foo", "org.bar");
return newString.getBytes("utf-8");
```

Comment: I have read adarshr's response and I think it's better than mine.

Comment: And I was thinking the other way round :)

Comment: this will only work if you have the complete stream in the byte array or otherwise sure that the byte array does not end in the middle of a multi-byte character.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to wrap your InputStream in your own FilterInputStream subclass that does the transformation on the fly. It will have to be a look-ahead stream that checks every "c" character to see if it is followed by "om.foo" and if so make the substitution. You'll probably have to override just the `read()` method.

Answer (score 1):

A stream reads/writes bytes. Trying to replace text in a binary representation is asking for trouble. So the first thing to do would be wrapping this stream into a Reader (like InputStreamReader) which will take care of translating the binary data into character information for you. You'll have to know the encoding of your streamed data, however, to make sure it is interpreted correctly. For example, UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1.

Once you have your textual data, you can think of how to replace parts of it. One way to do this is using regular expressions. However, this means you'll first have to read the entire stream into a string, do the substitution and then return the byte array. For large amounts of data, this might be inefficient.

Since you're dealing with XML data, you could make use of a higher-level approach and parse the XML in some way that allows you to process the contents without having to store them entirely in an intermediate format. A SAXParser with your own ContentHandler would do the trick. As events arrive, simply write them out again but with the proper alterations. Another approach would be an XSLT transformation with some extension function magic.

Wasn't there supposed to be some support for stream manipulations like this in java.nio? Or was this planned for an upcoming Java version?

Comment: Good advise on binary representation and encodings. Bad advises about regular expressions and XML. Why complicate things if only simple string replacement is needed? =0 in total

Comment: It's a lot of overhead to convert the entire stream to characters, do the substitution, and then convert everything back to bytes (which is what OP needs in the end). It's also unnecessary. The characters in "com.foo" gets encoded as single bytes. Even if that weren't the case, it would be far cheaper to convert the search and substitution patterns once to UTF-8, rather than round-trip the entire stream to and from characters.

Comment: @Ted Hopp 'The characters in "com.foo" gets encoded as single bytes' is not true. In many encodings they are not, so converting to characters may be necessary.

Comment: @unbeli - Hello? This is an XML stream that (according to the standard) identifies itself as UTF-8 by not specifying an encoding. Even if it were some weird encoding, converting the pattern and substitution strings is still the cheaper way to go by far.

Comment: @Ted Hopp Hello? Where does it identify itself as UTF-8? Even if it would, where does it say it will be like that for every stream in the future? Agreed, converting the pattern instead of the stream is a good idea for simple cases, when the pattern has a single representation in the target encoding.

Comment: @unbeli You're right about regular expressions... For a string like that, it would not be needed. However, I stand by the XML parsing stuff. Sure, it complicates things, but you wouldn't believe how brittle code is that replaces text in XML documents without regarding them as such. Markup is easy to break. For the "com.foo" example it isn't an issue, but one badly placed double quote or `<` will ruin your format.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient way to do it, but it certainly works.

```
    InputStream is = // input;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(baos));

    String line = null;

    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(line.contains("com.foo"))
        {
            line = line.replace("com.foo", "org.bar");
        }

        writer.write(line);
    }

    return baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Assumes input has reasonably sized lines. Replaces only one occurrence per line. No need to check with contains() before replace(). No need for BuffederWriter.